# React image on click get border

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a little project for Kids xD.  I need to input some images from massive with map, and I need the images to have `onClick` function - to get some blue borders for images.

I mapped array of images sources to `<div>`s with `<img>` contained.

But all divs goes to one Column. Any ideas about how to fix that? and there is another problem that I can't find tutorial about how to set border for `<div>` on Click, only `*:active`. In this app, kids must be able to check multiple photos. Any help is thankful ;)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.selected = this.selected.bind(this);
        this.state = {items: []}
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/items")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result =>{
            this.setState({
                isLoaded:true,
                items: result
            })
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }

selected(e){
console.log(e.target.img)
this.state.items.map(item =>{
    if (item.img==e.target.id){
    return(
        this.setState({item:{
            isSelected: !this.state.items.isSelected}})
)
}})       
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <h1 align="center">Choose Kitchen Tools</h1>
        {this.state.items.map((item) =>
    <div className="divas"> <img src={item.img} onClick={this.selected}/></div>
        ) } 
        </div>         
    )

}

}


export default App
```

```
class UserApiController {


    constructor() {
        this.getUsers = this.getUsers.bind(this)
      //  this.findUser = this.findUser.bind(this)

    }

    _virtuve() {
        return [
            {img: "/images/Keptuve.jpg",  isSelected:false, isCorrect:true},
            {img: "/images/Peilis.jpg",  isSelected:false, isCorrect:true},
            {img: "/images/Kamuolys.jpg",  isSelected:false, isCorrect:false},
            {img: "/images/Sakute.jpg",  isSelected:false, isCorrect:true},
            {img: "/images/Piestukai.jpg",  isSelected:false, isCorrect:false},
            {img: "/images/Lekste.jpg", isSelected:false, isCorrect:true},
            {img: "/images/Sukos.jpg",  isSelected:false, isCorrect:false},
            {img: "/images/Puodas.jpg",  isSelected:false, isCorrect:true},
            {img: "/images/Kompiuteris.jpg", isSelected:false, isCorrect:false},
            {img: "/images/Kojines.jpg", isSelected:false, isCorrect:false},

        ]
    } 

    getUsers(req, res, next) {
        const items = this._virtuve()
        return res.json(items)
    }


   /* findUser(req, res, next) {
        const userId = parseInt(req.body.userId) || 0
        const users = this._usersList()
        const amount = users.length
        let result = {}
        for (let i=0; i < amount; i++) {
            let user = users[i]
            if (user.id == userId) {
                result = user
                break
            }

        }
            return res.json(result)


    }
*/
}


module.exports = UserApiController
```

```
img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
.divas{
    width: 106px;
    height: auto;
    border: 3pt dashed blue;
}
.divas:active{
    border: 3pt dashed red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow entirely following but it sounds like you want to set a blue border if a user clicks on the image.

If so you can simply check if the item contains a class. In the example below, we use the `toggle` function to toggle a class on or off.

**css**

```
.selected {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**js**

```
 selected(e) {
    let target = e.currentTarget;
    target.classList.toggle('selected')
  }
```

To have the items wrap and not display in a column, you have two options:

1) You change the containing div's display type from `block` to `inline`. `inline` elements will take up the minimum space they require to display and don't start on a new line. This allows elements to wrap.

```
.divas {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

2) You specify the display type of `flex` on the diva's container and set the `flex-wrap` property to allow the child elements to wrap.

```
.divas-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfp4qm0u/)

Comment: Thanks it worked, now i can select multiple images, but now.. how i can get that images not in one column?

Answer (score 0):

command

```
this.state.items.map(item =>{
    if (item.img==e.target.id){
    return(
        this.setState({item:{
            isSelected: !this.state.items.isSelected}})
)
}})
```

is wrong.
array.map command does not modify array itself, it returns new array.
you should have something like that

```
let newItems= items.map(item=> ...);
this.setState({items:newItems})
```